# Rails: Multiple models records list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I show recent added @post and @photos in one list? For example:

```
post - LAlala (10.10.2011)
photos - [] [] [] [] (1.1.2011)
post - Bbbdsfbs (2.12.2010)
post - Lasdasdf2 (2.10.2009)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@posts = Post.limit(20).order('created_at desc')
@photos = Photo.limit(20).order('created_at desc')
@recent_items = (@posts + @photos).sort_by(&:created_at)

<% @recent_items.each do |item| %>
  <% if item.class == "Photo" %>
    <%= image_tag item.url %>
  <% else %>
    <%= item.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, use `group_by` to do it like this:

```
@recent_items = (@posts + @photos).group_by(&:created_at)

<% @recent_items.each do |date, items| %>
    Date: <%= date %>
    <% items.each do |item| %>
      Show information here.
    <% end %>
<% end >
```

I would move the view logic into a helper if I were you for DRYer code.

Comment: great! but how I can paginate this?

Comment: That depends on what you're using for pagination. Post a separate question.

Comment: Was there ever a follow-up post on paginating this?

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to do this is the database.

I just say this: polymorphism + database views.

Create a database view which contains the columns you need from both **Post** and **Photo**, including the column "**type**" containing a the name of the model (you need it for the polymorphism). Call this view for example "**list_items**". Then create a model called "**ListItem**". Then you can use this model like any other, paginate it and whatever you need to do.

```
ListItem.order("created_at > ?", Date.yesterday).page(params[:page])
```

And don't forget to configure the [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

However, all this is much easier to accomplish with the [listable](https://rubygems.org/gems/listable) gem. Check it out!